# Parent Child Hierachy in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, self-join, table-per-hierarchy

[image]

I want to show family hierachy in asp.net.

I have table as Family with attributes ParentID, ChildID, Name. Table have seft join on ParentID and ChildID. How I show the data from database. The hierarchy level is not fix.

**#edited**

I want aspx part to show this hierarchy tree i.e How I will show this tree in aspx using reapeater or other any control.

Answer (score 0):

Just create table in Database 'Person','ParentChild'. 'Person' table with columns Id and Name, 'ParentChild' with columns ParentId and ChildId. ParentId and ChildId will have reference to Id column in 'Person' table, so you can save easy your hierarchy, and get with query.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you have shown here is like a tree. So the simplest approach will be to implement SQL tree at the backend. Once you have done that there is a tree view control in asp.net that you can use to show up the data on front end. The best i could find is [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140827/Dynamic-Binding-Of-Hierarchy-Data-Structure-To-Tre)

Comment: I want to show tree as shown in the diagram not as a collapse expand tree view.

Comment: for this you should I will recommend using jquery plugin [jOrgChart](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html) just populate a list using asp.net and use jQuery plugin to display

Comment: if the solution provided answers your query pls vote and accept else comment

Comment: I have a structure of that tree but I am not able to bind the data to tree from c# to Aspx

Comment: have you gone through the tutorial well